# How do I change how data is binned for geom_hex()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Could someone point me to an example of how to use something other than `..count..` for the fill?  I have a data set with over 100k observations of two variables on [0,1] and a set of weights.  I want to make a scatterplot that shows the structure of the data without relying on a sample.  Right now I am using alpha for the overplotting and size for the weights like this:

```
ggplot( data= cropScatDf, aes( agland, nomos1, size= weight)) +
  geom_point( alpha= 0.03) +
  scale_area( limits= c(0.7, 1),
             breaks= seq( 0.7, by= 0.1),
             to= c(0.7, 1) *6)
```

And it works okay, but the visual quality varies depeding on my `ggsave()` settings.  So now I have this:

```
ggplot( data=cropScatDf, aes( agland, nomos1)) + 
   stat_binhex( binwidth=c(0.05, 0.05)) + 
   scale_fill_gradientn( colours= brewer.pal( 6, "YlGn"), 
                        trans= "log10", 
                        limits=c(100,50000))
```

and this does a pretty good job of showing the structure but I want to be able to say that I have applied the weights to the bins rather than just accepting a straight count.  Is this possible?  I imagine there is some subtlety of the grammar that I am not grasping.  Is there a way that I can cook my data before bringing it to `ggplot()` to get the desired effect?  Can I write my own transformer?

Comment: This has the added benefit of working better for PDF output!  :)

Comment: Currently `stat_binhex` doesn't support weights, but I have an experimental version in the `densityvis` package that does.  This will hopefully make it into the next version of ggplot2.

Comment: If you post a small reproducible example, we can give more specific advice.